# Post request body google api

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to create a draft in gmail using google api.

After authorization I am having trouble using POST to send request body. Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
var token = hash[1].split('=')[1]; // getting token
var body = "some text";
var base64message = Base64.encode(body); //uses base64 library to encode message
var params ={
    "message": {
        "raw": base64message
    }
}
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function(){
    console.log(this.responseText); // parseError
}

request.open('POST','https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token='+token,true);
request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Solved forgot this:

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
request.onload = function(){
    console.log(this.responseText); // parseError
}
```

Use `onreadystatechange` after which you ask `if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){`.

1. `this.readyState == 4` means that the request is finished or processed
2. `this.status == 200` means that it also succeeded.

`.onload` was added in XMLHttpRequest 2 whereas `onreadystatechange` has been around since the original spec. `.onload` is equal only to `this.readyState == 4`.

So your code will look like this:

```
var token = hash[1].split('=')[1]; // getting token
var body = "some text";
var base64message = Base64.encode(body); //uses base64 library to encode message
var params ={
    "message": {
        "raw": base64message
    }
};

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};

request.open('POST','https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token='+token,true);
request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve the problem. I am getting status 400, that's why i changed to onload to see what google has to say.

Comment: @PenPen 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules.